# What is view.Image in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using the non minified version of ember.js (1.0.0-RC.6), each views have an Image attribute (view.Image).
This isn't the case using the minified version and you cannot override this attribute.
You can find an example here: http://jsbin.com/oconiw/3/.
Does anyone know about this attribute ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! I think the `Image` is an alias to `HTMLImageElement` of the browser. Comparing it via an `{{action}}` confirms this.

The application view hierarchy is `View|MetamorphView > CoreView > Object`.

Better question, How does Image get there and why does it disappear in min? :)